# Android unloads data file during inactivity

Tags: android

I have a quiz app that loads a question database from a plist file. When the app is freshly loaded it runs a thread to load the question file.

After some inactivity, when you open the app again and try to run a new quiz, it loads no questions.

I imagine its some sort of garbage collector that the OS uses to clear up some memory, it's doing its job so thats ok.

But what would you recommended for reload the file? I'm thinking overriding savedInstanceState?

This is a splash screen and loader combination that is the first activity to run

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. **/
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new LoadViewTask().execute();
    }


    private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{  
      //Before running code in separate thread  
        @Override  
        protected void onPreExecute(){  
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreen.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setTitle("Loading File");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }  

        //The code to be executed in a background thread.  
        @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){   
            try{  
                //Get the current thread's token  
                synchronized (this){  
                    QuestionsLoader.getInstance(SplashScreen.this);                     
                }     
            }  
            catch (Exception e){  
                e.printStackTrace();  
                Log.d("TAG", "exception" + e);
            }
            return null;  
        }  

        //Update the progress  
        @Override  
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){  
        }   

        //after executing the code in the thread  
        @Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){  
        dialog.dismiss();
        Intent i = new Intent("com.project.AnActivity");
        startActivity(i); 
        finish(); //Finish the splash screen
        }  

    }  
}
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with garbage collection and Android is not "unloading" anything.  Your activity has been destroyed, as documented, when your app was in the background and you have a bug in your loading code and/or you are not handling the activity lifecycle properly.

Comment: Yes thats a good point, I can see what you mean. I think the instance of QuestionLoader gets flushed. Perhaps if I make another reference to it in the next activity it wont go missing.

Comment: Is `SplashScreen` an `Activity`?  If so, you should not attempt to retain a reference to it.  Android destroys activities to free memory when needed.  It is indeterminate when this happens and you should not interfere with the mechanism.  Without seeing the code, it's impossible to know but usually the correct approach is to load external resources in onResume() or later such that they are available whether the Activity is a new instance (e.g. onCreate() has been called) or the same instance returning to the foreground.

Comment: That was a good point in the right direction. Please answer do that I may accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is SplashScreen an Activity? If so, you should not attempt to retain a reference to it.

Android destroys activities to free memory when needed. It is indeterminate when this happens and you should not interfere with the mechanism.   It doesn't use the garbage collector to do this (it destroys the Activity's process) so if you hold a reference to it, you will leak the entire activity which is not good.  You see many apps on the Play Store with this particular bug, or a variant of it.  Just rotate the device 5 or 10 times and the app will crash with out of memory.

Without seeing the code, it's impossible to know but usually the correct approach is to load external resources in `onResume()` or later such that they are available whether the Activity is a new instance (e.g. `onCreate()` has been called) or the same instance returning to the foreground.

If you need to persist some state regardless of whether the activity is destroyed or not, save it (usually to `SharedPreferences`) in `onPause()` and retrieve it in `onResume()`.